# How to turn on alpha channel?

Tags: graphicsmagick

My English is not good. I apologize and let's go straight to a simple example.

```
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick(NULL);
    Magick::Image *img = new Magick::Image();
    img->magick("RGBA");
    img->size(Magick::Geometry(150, 150));
    img->read("xc:transparent");
    img->fillColor(Magick::Color(0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF));
    img->lineWidth(10);
    img->strokeColor(Magick::Color(0xFF, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00));
    img->draw(Magick::DrawableCircle(75,75,75,10));
    img->write("foo.png");
    delete img;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I tried to draw an orange circle and write the result to a .png file. If you open the .png with GIMP or some other image editor, you might notice that the border of the circle is ugly, especially when you open it as a layer on some other colorful image. The border is not transparent gradually. It uses black color in the position of transparency. Apparently it's using mask not alpha channel. What am I missing here? What method should I call and where? Thanks. :)

Comment: Posting the resulting image would be useful!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reply. It is a confirmed and fixed bug (fixed in development version). If interested, you might check it out at https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/bugs/558/ where there are images detailing the issue.